# Supress PowerShell prompting "Press any key to continue..."

Tags: powershell, batch-file, scripting, windows-server

I'm running a powershell script from a .bat to make it double click friendly.  Here's the code:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -NoExit -command "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs" {<Location of .ps1 file here>; <arguments>; pause }
```

It runs fine but when it completes it says "Press any key to continue" and the powershell window closes but I need it to remain open because at the end of the script it displays some additional commands we need to run to complete the process.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To keep a PowerShell window open (its session alive) after executing a command with `-Command` (or `-File`), use the [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe)'s `-NoExit` parameter**, as already shown in your question for the *outer* PowerShell call.

You then have no need for an interactive delay-the-closing command such as `pause` (which is a function that simply calls `$null = Read-Host 'Press Enter to continue...'`).

Therefore:

- Add a `-NoExit` parameter to the *inner*, `Start-Process`-launched PowerShell instance as well or - more likely - *instead*; you need to scroll to the right to see it in the command below.
- Remove the `pause` command from the inner command string.

Note: I'm assuming that you don't actually need the outer `-NoExit`, as it would block the batch file indefinitely by entering an interactive PowerShell session, so it is omitted from the command below.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -command "Start-Process powershell -Verb RunAs '-NoExit', '-Command', '...'"
```

Note that there's no point in using a script block (`{ ... }`) with `Start-Process`, because only *strings* are supported as arguments by `Start-Process`; hence, `'...'` is used above to represent the command string to pass to the inner PowerShell instance.

Comment: Thank you!  I was able to use a variation of your suggestion to get it working as needed.  Moving the '-NoExit' was the main fix I was looking for but also it's worth noting I did need the scriptblock {...} in order for arguments to get passed through correctly but it's in working order now.  Appreciate your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @dschwartz0815. Yes, you can use a script block as a quasi-literal to help ease escaping pains around embedded quotes, but note that you're not actually passing a _script block_ to the target instance (though in this specific case it doesn't make much of a difference); basically, `.ToString()` is called on your script block literal (`{ ... }`), which is the same as taking its content _verbatim_, without the enclosing curly braces.

Comment: that makes sense to me.  You're probably right though, it was more than likely a syntax issue I was overlooking and using the script block was helping with my formatting.  I was staring at this for a while today.  Some fresh eyes probably would have gotten it working per your suggestion.